# Syntax issues when scraping data

Tags: python, web-scraping

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import csv
from urlparse import urljoin
import urllib2
from lxml import html

base_url = 'http://www.pro-football-reference.com' # base url for concatenation
data = requests.get("http://www.pro-football-reference.com/years/2014/games.htm") #website for scraping
soup = BeautifulSoup(data.content)
list_of_cells = []

for link in soup.find_all('a'):
    if link.has_attr('href'):
        if link.get_text() == 'boxscore':
            url = base_url + link['href']
            for x in url:
                response = requests.get('x')
                html = response.content
                soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
                table = soup.find('table', attrs={'class': 'stats_table x_large_text'})
                for row in table.findAll('tr'):
                    for cell in row.findAll('td'):
                        text = cell.text.replace('&nbsp;', '')
                        list_of_cells.append(text)
                        print list_of_cells
```

I am using the code in order to get all the boxscore urls from http://www.pro-football-reference.com/years/2014/games.htm. After I get these boxscore urls I would like to loop through them to scrape the quarter by quarter data for each team but my syntax always seems to be off no matter how I format the code.

If it is possible I would like to scrape more than just the scoring data by also getting the Game Info, officials, and Expected points per game.

Answer (score 0):

If you modify your loop slightly to:

```
for link in soup.find_all('a'):

    if not link.has_attr('href'):
        continue

    if link.get_text() != 'boxscore':
        continue

    url = base_url + link['href']

    response = requests.get(url)
    html = response.content
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html)

    # Scores
    table = soup.find('table', attrs={'id': 'scoring'})
    for row in table.findAll('tr'):
        for cell in row.findAll('td'):
            text = cell.text.replace('&nbsp;', '')
            list_of_cells.append(text)
            print list_of_cells
```

That returns each of the cells for each row in the scoring `table` for each page linked to with the 'boxscore' text.

The issues I found with the existing code were:

1. You were attempting to loop through each character in the `href` returned for the 'boxscore' link.
2. You were always requesting the string `'x'`.
3. Not so much an issue, but I changed the table selector to identify the table by its `id` 'scoring' rather than the `class`. Ids at least should be unique within the page *(though there is no guarentee)*.

I'd recommend that you find each `table` (or HTML element) containing the data you want in the main loop (e.g `score_table = soup.find('table'...`) but that you move the code that parses that data (e.g)...

```
for row in table.findAll('tr'):
    for cell in row.findAll('td'):
        text = cell.text.replace('&nbsp;', '')
        list_of_cells.append(text)
        print list_of_cells
```

...into a separate function that returns said data (one for each type of data you are extracting), just to keep the code slightly more manageable. The more the code indents to handle `if` tests and `for` loops the more difficult it tends to be to follow the flow. For example:

```
score_table = soup.find('table', attrs={'id': 'scoring'})
score_data = parse_score_table(score_table)

other_table = soup.find('table', attrs={'id': 'other'})
other_data = parse_other_table(other_table)
```